# how I can download files from master to branch

Tags: git

I did some adjustments on some files within the master branch and now I want to get the same changes to the same files in branch. how I can transfer the changes from master to branch?

Comment: Are you wanting to merge everything that changed in master into your other branch?

Comment: Do you want all the changes you did in some commits to be copied to another branch?

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve a specific file from a specific branch, you can do this:

```
>$ git checkout my-branch
>$ git checkout master -- path/to/some/file
```

Comment: I want to substitute all files in master to the branch.

Comment: You want to overwrite all of the files in your branch with the versions in master? Why not create a new branch?

Answer (score 1):

First You need to get an clone from your repository

Use **git clone 'Your git repository URL'**

Then

**git branch**

it will shows all available branches and highlighted with your current branch
if you are not in master branch please checkout with

**git checkout origin master**

after you can use

**git checkout -b 'new branch_name'**

Then your new branch will create with the master branch files

Comment: I type git branch in git bash and get "fatal:  not a git repository.... " error